# What happens to exported global variables when a DLL is linked in multiple times?

Tags: c++, c, windows, dll

Suppose I have a `X.DLL` with the following in a header file:

```
extern __declspec(dllexport) int foobar;
```

This `foobar` global variable is then defined inside `X.DLL` in an implementation file:

```
int foobar = 1;
```

Now suppose that I have two DLLs, `A.DLL` and `B.DLL`, which are linked to `X.DLL`, and an application `E.EXE` which uses `A.DLL` and `B.DLL`:

```
          +----> A.DLL ----+
          |                |
E.EXE ----+                +----> X.DLL
          |                |
          +----> B.DLL ----+
```

In this situation, is the expression `&foobar` (address of `foobar`) guaranteed to have the same value when evaluated inside `A.DLL` and `B.DLL`? In other words, are `X.DLL`'s global variables stored twice or is there only one instance of `foobar` in the entire process? Also, does it make a difference if the DLLs are linked at load time or through a call to [`LoadLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

I'm also confused by this statement in GCC's [documentation for dllimport](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html):

> One drawback to using this attribute is that a pointer to a *variable* marked as `dllimport` cannot be used as a constant address.

I don't quite understand the implications of that statement considering my aforementioned situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one copy. However, in general, doing this is an incredibly bad idea and you will run into a lot of problems.